# Two inputs to one model in Keras

Tags: python, image, vector, keras

Is it possible in Keras to feed both an image and a vector of values as inputs to one model? If yes, how?

What I want is to create a CNN with an image and a vector of 6 values on the input.

The output is the vector of 3 values.

Comment: Yes, you have to use a Siamese network for this.

Comment: That is not quite right, @MatiasValdenegro. Usually, Siamese networks are two weight-sharing branches (same sequence of layers) that process a data pair of the same modality (eg., two images or two arrays).  The answer goes more in the line of what sdcbr posted.

Comment: @rafaspadilha you can have a siamese network that doesn't share weights.

Comment: I don't think they are called Siamese when they don't share weights. But leaving nomenclature aside, you are right.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, please have a look at Keras' [Functional API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/) for many examples on how to build models with multiple inputs.

Your code will look something like this, where you will probably want to pass the image through a convolutional layer, flatten the output and concatenate it with your vector input:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, Conv2D, Flatten, Dense
from keras.models import Model

# Define two input layers
image_input = Input((32, 32, 3))
vector_input = Input((6,))

# Convolution + Flatten for the image
conv_layer = Conv2D(32, (3,3))(image_input)
flat_layer = Flatten()(conv_layer)

# Concatenate the convolutional features and the vector input
concat_layer= Concatenate()([vector_input, flat_layer])
output = Dense(3)(concat_layer)

# define a model with a list of two inputs
model = Model(inputs=[image_input, vector_input], outputs=output)
```

This will give you a model with the following specs:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_8 (InputLayer)            (None, 32, 32, 3)    0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 30, 30, 32)   896         input_8[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_9 (InputLayer)            (None, 6)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)             (None, 28800)        0           conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 28806)        0           input_9[0][0]                    
                                                                 flatten_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 3)            86421       concatenate_3[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 87,317
Trainable params: 87,317
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Another way to visualize it is through [Keras' visualization utilities](https://keras.io/api/utils/model_plotting_utils/):

[image]

Comment: What is the format of x on functions such as model.fit() when this is used?

Comment: With model.fit(), that would be a list of numpy arrays for this example.

Comment: If you have a model with 2 inputs during training, but only 1 input during inference, do you have to fill the second input with a zero array? Or is there a way to pass nothing into the second input and ignore the second output as well to avoid tensorflow having to execute the second branch?

Comment: It's possible to export only a part of the model graph for inference. In the example above, one could export `input_8 -> convd2d_4 -> flatten_3`, to feed it with a single input and get the output of the convolutional layer as a result. It wouldn't be possible to go one step further and include `concatenate_3`, without including `input_9` as well. Also, feeding only zeros does does not pass as a 'blank' input, since bias weights will be added to these zeroes throughout the layers of the network.