# In Keras, how to pairwise concatenate two inputs of different input size?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

As a motivating example, say we have an edge weight prediction problem in a network of heterogenous nodes, e.g. images and text, and want the concatenation of every possible pair of inputs. A simple example of what the data might look like:

```
# two inputs of different shape
x = np.array([[1, 1],
              [2, 2],
              [3, 3]])
y = np.array([[4, 4, 4],
              [5, 5, 5]])

# a predicted feature we'd like to model
z= np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])

joined = np.array([[1, 1, 4, 4, 4], 
                   [1, 1, 5, 5, 5], 
                   [2, 2, 4, 4, 4], 
                   [2, 2, 5, 5, 5], 
                   [3, 3, 4, 4, 4], 
                   [3, 3, 5, 5, 5]])
some_model.fit(inputs=[x,y], outputs=z)
```

And an example model (shown with dense layers, but in spirit this could be any layer or sequence of layers):

[image]

Concatenation is [simple enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516662/two-inputs-in-one-with-keras) per this other answer, and inputs [needn't be of the same size](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/11548), but I'm not sure whether and how one can create this kind of model.

Is there a straightforward way to achieve this in Keras?

Comment: what is `z` for?

Comment: Whoops, left that out :) A predicted feature we'd like to model as output, edited to reflect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tf.tile()`, `tf.reshape()` and `tf.concat()`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_data = np.array([[1, 1],
                   [2, 2],
                   [3, 3]], dtype=np.float32)
y_data = np.array([[4, 4, 4],
                   [5, 5, 5]], dtype=np.float32)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))
xshape = tf.shape(x)
yshape = tf.shape(y)
newshape = (xshape[0] * yshape[0], xshape[1] + yshape[1])

xres = tf.tile(x, multiples=[1, yshape[0]])
xres = tf.reshape(xres, [newshape[0], xshape[1]])
# `x` is now: [[1. 1.]
#              [1. 1.]
#              [2. 2.]
#              [2. 2.]
#              [3. 3.]
#              [3. 3.]]
yres = tf.tile(y, multiples=[xshape[0], 1])
# `y` is now: [[4. 4. 4.]
#              [5. 5. 5.]
#              [4. 4. 4.]
#              [5. 5. 5.]
#              [4. 4. 4.]
#              [5. 5. 5.]]
res = tf.concat([xres, yres], axis=1) # <-- this is your result
with tf.Session() as sess:
    evaled = res.eval({x:x_data, y:y_data})
    print(evaled)
# [[1. 1. 4. 4. 4.]
#  [1. 1. 5. 5. 5.]
#  [2. 2. 4. 4. 4.]
#  [2. 2. 5. 5. 5.]
#  [3. 3. 4. 4. 4.]
#  [3. 3. 5. 5. 5.]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer made me realize my question wasn't written to get at my real problem, and helped focus a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55944416/in-keras-or-tensorflow-how-to-input-different-sample-sizes-and-pairwise-concate) on what I'm really looking to do. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look.