# In Keras or Tensorflow, how to input different sample sizes and pairwise concatenate embeddings within a model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

In follow-up to [this question], a few notes on what we're looking to accomplish:

- We have two inputs `X` and `Y` of different sample sizes `n` and `m`, and a boolean vector `z` of size `nm`. Each element of `z` denotes whether two items in `X` and `Y` are some sort of match
- We want to use embedding layers (perhaps the same, perhaps different) on `X` and `Y` before pairwise concatenating the output of these embedding layers to derive input to an output layer.

Here's one example of what a simple network could look like:

[image]

The linked answer and a few other resources helped get as far as this example, which builds a model but throws this error at fit time: `ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(10, 2), (12, 2)]`.

Recent versions of Keras [allow for skipping the dimension check](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/11548), can this check be skipped in Tensorflow? I'd also be happy to use Keras, but I'm not sure how to perform the reshape and concatenate in Keras in the middle of a model.

Or, is this simply not possible in either? Is the only option to expand and pairwise concatenate **prior** to input?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

k = 2
N = 10
M = 12

x = np.random.randint(2, size = 2 * N).reshape((-1,2))
y = np.random.randint(2, size = 2 * M).reshape((-1,2))

x_rep = np.tile(x, (1, M)).reshape((-1,2))
y_rep = np.tile(y, (N, 1))

xy = np.concatenate((x_rep, y_rep), axis=1)
xy = xy.astype(bool)
z = (xy[:,0] == xy[:,2]) * (xy[:,1] ^ xy[:,3])

print(z[:20])
xy = xy.astype(int)
z = z.astype(int)


first = keras.Input(shape=(k,))
second = keras.Input(shape=(k,))

shared_dense = layers.Dense(k)

first_dense = shared_dense(first)
second_dense = shared_dense(second)

first_tiled = layers.Lambda(tf.tile, arguments={'multiples':[1, M]}, name='first_expanded' )(first_dense) #keras.backend.tile(first_dense, [1, M])
second_tiled = layers.Lambda(tf.tile, arguments={'multiples':[N,1]}, name='second_expanded')(second_dense) #keras.backend.tile(first_dense, [1, M])

first_reshaped = layers.Reshape((k,))(first_tiled)
concatenated = layers.Concatenate()([first_reshaped, second_tiled])
out = layers.Dense(1)(concatenated)
model = keras.Model([first, second], out)

keras.utils.plot_model(model, 'tf_nw.png', show_shapes=True)
model.compile('Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([x, y], z)
```

Comment: do you know the solution now?